# Gdbus property set form client not working

Tags: properties, gdbus

Based on the fatmimin hello world sample, I have added a property to the interface:

```
        <property name="Sputulant" type="i" access="readwrite"/>
```

make gen does its thing, resulting in two funcs called:

```
min_min_bus_gdbus_set_sputulant()
min_min_bus_gdbus_get_sputulant()
```

I havent added any code in server.c  to 'connect' to this property (in the way the Hello World method is, with g_signal_connect())

When calling these from the client only the get function works.   I cant set the value.

Using gdbus tool does work though:

```
gdbus call -e -d com.fatminmin -o /com/fatminmin/GDBUS -m org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set "com.fatminmin.GDBUS" "Sputulant" "<123>"
```

I have been digging into this for days now and cant find any sample code for properties or any other suggestions, so what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using this from the client works though:

```
con = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION, NULL, &error);
     
result = g_dbus_connection_call_sync (con,                             "com.fatminmin",        "/com/fatminmin/GDBUS",        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",       "Set", g_variant_new("(ssv)", "com.fatminmin.GDBUS", "Sputulant", g_variant_new("i", 235)),      NULL,        G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE, -1, NULL,      &error);

g_object_unref(con);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the cause of this is you cant do a set property with the same proxy handle you used to do a get property.

So,

```
proxy = lkbr_bus_gdbus_proxy_new_for_bus_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION, G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_NONE,
"com.lkbr", "/com/lkbr/GDBUS", NULL, &error);

lkbr_bus_gdbus_set_sputulant(proxy,  235);
g_object_unref(proxy);
```

Works, create a new proxy, and unref it, for each call seems to be the way to go